# Parsing a Powershell exported password in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, security, powershell

I have an XML file containing an encrypted version of a username and password. We use this for our powershell scripts. Now instead of using a different method for keeping username and password, I'd like my .NET applications to use this XML file as well.

This is the Powershell code:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName "myusername" -Message "Credentials"
$cred | Export-CliXml "C:\Users\degruy43\documents\myencryptedcredentials.xml"
```

The format of the XML file is this:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="UserName">myusername@domain.com</S>
      <SS N="Password">01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000a144ed33923dc84c8ba21f593965ed7c00000000020000000000106600000001000020000000eec6eedf19e08e2197b866b2a7ef35f7649252ca7d53be654647e9c7bb1e2442000000000e8000000002000020000000e0016da2a4c0155eb4f31b722c7fb319d6b5a2c0bc8faf23c43797bf099c840520000000ebedc8ebdee117b24f5edd53cf2d6cc50259c07ee221281eb1858412121818e340000000e3c3163194b70f687bb6c1011b47a6b95291f9cc9aae4d121935ccbec73c578a452e3a4d70a9356cf5a44232cbf479ae6dc3aa2a37fada50f09826280324f65b</SS>
    </Props>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

So how can I use this file to build my secure string in .NET? I suppose that this IS the secure string?

Comment: Is this some sort of automation? I take it you actually need to use the password, and therefore it is encrypted and not hashed?

Comment: You can serialize the xml into  PSCredential  instance in C#.

Comment: You can use [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849818.aspx) to convert the `Password` string to a securestring

Comment: Thanks guys, I guesse I looked over it but indeed this is part of the System.Management.Automation namespace. With your tips I tried deserializing with PSSerializer .Deserialize but I get this error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in System.Security.dll

Additional information: Key not valid for use in specified state."

Any idea?

Comment: It could be so the underlying crypto library uses the key hardcoded on a machine. Which means you need to transfer the key in that particular location that it expects on all the machines where you need to decrypt it.

Comment: OK, thanks guys. It seems I had a little mix up with the accounts. I used the local administrator account for both the Powershell export and the .NET runtime account and now it works. Thanks!